# What happened to Orac?

Tags: blakes-7

It's been a while since I watched Blake's 7 and I can't for the life of me remember if Orac is still lying on a little grassy hill! Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: "[Orac was not with the rest of the crew when they had their final encounter with Blake; **its fate is unknown**.](http://blakes7.wikia.com/wiki/Orac)" Does this answer your question?

Comment: I thought that maybe Orac had been sequestered away by Avon and was still waiting to be picked up. I'll take it as an answer, I just wish there was a less mundane explanation.

Comment: Back when I originally answered this question, I knew nothing about *Blake's 7* except what Google, Wikipedia, and Wikia gave me. In the last two years I've watched the whole show, and just finished the last episode (wow, what a finale!) earlier this week. So now I've completely overhauled my answer to give much more and better information. Just wanted to let you know there's now a lot more than a couple of wiki quotes :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In the show, Orac's fate is unknown.

When Avon and the others come charging into the control room and find Tarrant, they do *not* have Orac with them. You can see this clearly in the few seconds when the camera focuses on the four of them as they enter the room:

[image: our heroes entering the room]

They *did* have it when they were coming in on the flyer earlier: specifically, Soolin was holding it. This is Orac's very last appearance on-screen:

[image: Orac's last appearance]

So they must have sequestered it somewhere before coming to find Tarrant and Blake. Maybe they left it in the flyer, or more likely they found a better hiding place in the silo or on their way.

### In non-canon novels, Orac (and Avon) survived.

There are a number of stories written [Post Gauda Prime](https://fanlore.org/wiki/Post-Gauda_Prime). Most of these, of course, are fan fiction with no hope of being considered canonical. There are a couple which were actually published and written by people with some connection to the show, so they're the most likely to be taken seriously, although still not usually considered canon.

- In [*Afterlife*](https://fanlore.org/wiki/Afterlife_(Blake%27s_7_tie-in_book)), a novel written by Tony Attwood (who also wrote the *Blake's 7* Programme Guide), both Avon and Vila survive the shootout in the final episode, and they escape together with Orac.
- In [*Lucifer*](https://books.google.com.cy/books/about/Lucifer.html?id=vlnemgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y), a novel written by the late Paul Darrow (who played Avon in the show, and even [owned the rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Darrow) to *Blake's 7* at one time), only Avon and Orac survive Gauda Prime.

So if you want information about Orac's fate at and after Gauda Prime, it exists in a published book written by one of the principal people involved with the show. But within the show itself, or what's usually considered to be the *Blake's 7* canon, there's no information about where Orac ended up.